# Django Form not rendering/loading in BS modal

Tags: python, django

i am trying to get a Form into a BS modal but the modal is always empty.
Searched very much for a solution but nothing worked yet and im helpless.
As im quite new to Python and Django i tried to set up a small Event page for updating/adding/deleting Events and Venues for Events.

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Event, Venue
from .forms import VenueForm, EventForm
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

def add_event(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_event?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = EventForm
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True

    return render(request, 'events/add_event.html', {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted})

def list_venues(request):
    venue_list = Venue.objects.all().order_by(Lower('name'))
    return render(request, 'events/venues.html', {
        "venue_list": venue_list,
    })


def add_venue(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VenueForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = VenueForm
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
    return render(request, 'events/add_venue.html', {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted})

def all_events(request):
    event_list = Event.objects.all().order_by(Lower('name'))
    return render(request, 'events/event_list.html', {
        "event_list": event_list,
    })
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # in
    path('events/', views.all_events, name="list-events"),
    path('add_venue', views.add_venue, name="add-venue"),
    path('list_venues', views.list_venues, name="list-venues"),
    path('add_event', views.add_event, name="add-event"),
]
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Venue Name', max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    zip_code = models.CharField('ZIP Code', max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length=120)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField('Event Date')
    venue = models.ForeignKey(
        Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

at first i have created simple html files to be opened and passed the form in like

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
```

which worked perfectly. (Done this with both forms add Event and add Venue)
Now i tried to change the add_Venue From, to get it into a BS Modal but it is keeping empty.

My add_event.html is loocking like this:

```
{% extends 'events/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Add Event..</h1>
    <br/><br />    
    <form action="" method=POST>
        {% csrf_token %}        
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
    <br /><br />
{% endblock %}
```

And the add_Venue.html with the Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addVenueModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addVenueModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addVenueModalLabel">Add Venue2</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container txt-box">
                    <form action="" role="form" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to call this from every page i have thats why i added the button into the navbar:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Events
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right:auto; left: auto; text-align:left;">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'list-events' %}">list Events</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'add-event' %}">Add Event</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown" >
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Venues
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right:auto; left: auto; text-align:left;">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'list-venues' %}">list Venues</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addVenueModal">Add Venue</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

(this is just the snipped from the navbar)

i also included the add_venue.html into my base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% include 'events/navbar.html' %}

    <br/>
    <div class="container">
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                
                <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content%}
        {% include 'events/add_venue.html' %}
    </div>
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    
    <!-- script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

I really tried everything i found but nothing worked so far.
One thing i figured out was, calling the add_event.html and then calling the modal the add_event form is beeing loaded inside the modal.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got this finally myself. Just wanted to post the solution, if anyone else have the same problem. If i am explaining something wrong please correct me.

Above you can see that my djangoforms are already built. (forms.py)
Im using a navbar.html for navigation and included this into my base.html.

What i have done:

Changed the add_venue view in
views.py:

```
def add_venue(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VenueForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'success': True})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': form.errors})
    else:
        form = VenueForm()
        return JsonResponse({'html': render_to_string('events/add_venue_form.html', {'form': form}, request=request)})
```

Then i changed my add_venue.html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready");
        $('#venueModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            console.log("modal show");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "{% url 'add-venue' %}",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("ajax success");
                    $('#venueModal .modal-body').html(data.html);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log("ajax error");
                    alert('An error occurred while loading the form.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="venueModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="venueModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="venueModalLabel">Venue hinzufügen</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Hier wird das Formular eingesetzt -->
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but this is not enough because form is not rendering.
created a add_venue_from.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
</form>
```

(see the view response)
making sure urls.py in correct:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # in
    ...
    path('add_venue', views.add_venue, name="add-venue"),
    ...
]
```

make sure JQuery and JS is in base.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
{% load static %}
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap5.modal.forms.js' %}"></script>
```

and include the add_venue.html also in base.html

```
{% include 'events/add_venue.html' %}
```

this is just about rendering the form! Not done the submit function.
Will add this to the answer when i have it.

EDIT:

to save the form:
add_venue_form.html:

```
<form method="POST" id="venueForm" action="{% url 'add-venue' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
</form>
```

now the form will be saved.

Comment: If i have done something not neccessary or wrong please correct me aswell